# Started Python today, and came to a problem i couldnt really solve

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to dive into Python and I came to a problem when I wanted to make a very primitive calculator.

It asks you to type 2 numbers, and then it would display informations like number1 + number 2 etc.

I was at the point where I was typing in to display a short text and then the amount of the two numbers like `print("amount:" number1 + number2)` and that one wasn't right, it was just putting the two numbers next to each other, not what they equal.

I don't know how to display it somehow like this (for example):

```
The two number equals: 100
```

Comment: Not only would a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help us figure out what's going wrong, but it would also help us tell *you* what's wrong.

Comment: Have a look at [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427). At the moment you are adding two strings together instead of two numbers, so it doesn't work as you're expecting it to.

Comment: so i was writing an answer but the question got closed so here's my comment.
you need to convert datatypes to same type in order to print. a small example below

=====================================================

a = int(input('enter first number'))
b = int(input('enter second number'))
c = a+b
d = a-b
e = a*b
f = a/b
oper = input('enter operator')
if (oper == '+'):
    print ('sum of a and b is', c)
if (oper == '-'):
    print ('subtract of a and b is', d)
if (oper == '*'):
    print ('multiple of a and b is', e)
if (oper == '/'):
    print ('devision of a and b is', f)

Answer (score 1):

You probably did:

```
a = input('number 1')
b = input('number 2')
print(a + b)
```

Here a and b will be `str` (strings are words or sentences). So if you do `+` it'll be like:

```
a = 'a_word'
b = 'another_word'
print('a_word'+'another_word')
>>> a_wordanother_word
```

What you want is to make the word into a number. You can do this by 'casting it' to an integer (a whole number) or a float (a number with a decimal):

```
a = int(input('number_1'))  # example: a = 5
b = float(input('number_2'))    # example: b = 1.2345
print(a + b)
>>> 6.2345
```

Comment: You need a medal for deciphering!

Comment: Thank you, now i understand how to have them as int or any other type of variable :) But still another question in my head is how can i print a string and then next to it number1 + number2 so it says "amount:" and then what the two number equals to

Comment: @Matee `f"amount: {number1 + number2}"` google string formatting

Comment: @mkieger1 what was the point of that edit? Some custom I'm not used to?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `number1 = input()`, you have to make it `number1 = int(input())` (you can also use float() or whatever) , otherwise your number is going to be a string.

Comment: Thank you, now i understand how to have them as int or any other type of variable :) But still another question in my head is how can i print a string and then next to it number1 + number2 so it says "amount:" and then what the two number equals to

Comment: You just have to print("Amount:",number1+number2)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to do but i think it should work for your case :

a = 10

b = 5

print(f'A + B =  {a+b}')